# kafka first implementation - error on producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using the sample code in the quickstart for apache-kafka implementation. I keep running into the following error when creating a new producer and not much details on the web for the error:

```
try {

        producer = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, String>(
        new ProducerConfig(props)); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PRODUCER Error"+ e);
    }
```

error that is created:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class scala.Tuple2$mcLL$sp overrides 
   final method _1.()Ljava/lang/Object;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
at com.datacollector.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:50)
at com.datacollector.MainProducerRawData.main(MainProducerRawData.java:117)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses. I finally figured it out. I need to run an updated versions of the scala and kafka libraries as they were not matching.